# Don't make a second level when aggregating in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Indexes and levels in Pandas still drive me nuts when using it.
My dataframe structure looks like that:

```
Indexstruktur   Datensatz   Workload    Selectivity     Dimensionen     Anzahl Datenpunkte  Operation   Measure     Wert
```

I now group by all columns except the last one ("Wert"). This one will be used to aggregate, where I calculate average and standard deviation:

```
mean_df = df.groupby(["Indexstruktur", "Datensatz","Workload", "Selectivity", "Dimensionen", "Anzahl Datenpunkte", "Operation", "Measure"]).agg({"Wert":['mean','std']})
mean_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The result are two levels:

```
index   Indexstruktur   Datensatz   Workload    Selectivity     Dimensionen     Anzahl Datenpunkte  Operation   Measure     Wert
                                                                                                                       mean     std
```

How can I get rid of "Wert" and just make "avg" and "std" two columns in the same level as the rest?

mean_df.columns returns:

```
MultiIndex([(     'Indexstruktur',     ''),
            (         'Datensatz',     ''),
            (          'Workload',     ''),
            (       'Selectivity',     ''),
            (       'Dimensionen',     ''),
            ('Anzahl Datenpunkte',     ''),
            (         'Operation',     ''),
            (           'Measure',     ''),
            (              'Wert', 'mean'),
            (              'Wert',  'std')],
           )
```

I tried reset_index, droplevel, as_index=False, but nothing changes anything.
What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this should work for you
`mean_df = df.groupby(["Indexstruktur", "Datensatz","Workload", "Selectivity", "Dimensionen", "Anzahl Datenpunkte", "Operation", "Measure"])["Wert"].agg(['mean','std']).reset_index()` This would still have
"Indexstruktur", "Datensatz","Workload", "Selectivity", "Dimensionen", "Anzahl Datenpunkte", "Operation", "Measure" as columns though, but also agg and std. If you don't want that just do
`mean_df = df.groupby(["Indexstruktur", "Datensatz","Workload", "Selectivity", "Dimensionen", "Anzahl Datenpunkte", "Operation", "Measure"])["Wert"].agg(['mean','std']).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: My hero of the day, the first one works. Thank you